# Laravel Manage Online User List

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to keep a list of "Online" users for each account.

I poll the server every five seconds in my app telling it 'Hey this user is currently online'

Then I update all the other connected users interface to show that 'Hey this user is online.'

The problem I'm dealing with now is, once the server hasn't received that 'Hey I'm online' notification for x number of seconds, I want to go ahead and mark them 'Offline'.

I'm using laravel and thought maybe Events would work, maybe start and event that sleeps for 10 secs and checks to see if the timestamp from the users last 'check-in' is greater than ten seconds. But this raises questions of laravel events being queued? I know you can queue them which means regular events would just run on the same server request and not work as intended.

And if I do Q them, with only one listener wouldn't this congest the q with all these 'waiting' threads trying to reset a measly 'Online' boolean? Maybe multiple listeners?

What is the easiest way to have the server reset a DB value x number of seconds after something does/does not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php is synchronous, so anything involving runtime queues is going to give you a very big headache.

I know laravel 5 has some queue system (haven't used it myself) but the you need to create something that will consume that queue.

Best bet is to re-read the queue documentation in laravel, and also look at cron jobs.

These are automated tasks that you can set to run at set intervals. They can then process any persisted queue and update your database.

UPDATE:

Why are you saving a boolean? You can just save a timestamp `last_seen` in your DB. Then instead of your code checking the boolean to see if a user is online, it can just compare the `last_seen` stamp with the current timestamp. If greater than x seconds, then user is presumed offline. With laravel, you can even add this logic into the eloquent model for the database table. This means the logic does not have to be repeated everywhere its needed.

Comment: Yah I'm using laravel 4 and have queues set up with AWS but I'm questioning using them for this purpose. Cron jobs could be interesting. Thanks for some feedback.

Comment: also, why set a boolean value? Cant you have a timestamp 'last_seen' and then compare that timestamp with current time?

Comment: Yah I guess I could do that on the front end of other users and avoid this reset garbage all together coudn't I. Man sometimes this job make you feel silly.